# Importing private key to bitcoin node is slow. Can it be faster?

Tags: bitcoind, private-key, private-key-import

I have launched the bitcoin node and synchronized it. The issue is that importing the private key forces the node to scan the blockchain for the operations with the key. Is there a way to import the key in a fast way?

Comment: You can skip the rescan, but then you won't have transactions and can't spend existing outputs to it. Or if it was a recently created key, you can specify its birth time using `importmulti`, which will only rescan the chain after that point.

Comment: BIP158 blockfilterindex should help in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Bitcoin core is a full node and doesn't use SPV or any equivalent. Therefore, when *importing* a private key, it must scan the Blockchain copy it holds rather than trust third parties.

**Sweeping** the private key into Bitcoin core ought to be faster.

Comment: what do you mean by "sweeping"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is actually possible to "sweep" into Bitcoin Core like is possible with Electrum and other 3rd party wallets.  Core requires importing the key and scanning against transaction history from 2009. I'm beginning to think that for old BIP32 and BIP39 seeds it's the only way to recover coins.  It might take hours/days to scan.